# Direct two diferrent URL to the same page in JSF

Tags: jsf, url, navigation

I am developing a jsf2 + spring3 application with the following filesystem:

```
webapp
-resources (folder)
-WEB-INF (folder)
   --applicationContext.xml
   --faces-config.xml
   --web.xml
-buy.xhtml
-company.xhtml
-home.xhtml
-sell.xhtml
```

And I got this in my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My faces-config.xml got nothing about navigation.

When I go to the following URL "http://:8080/website/" I got the "home.jsf" view.
I need to go to the same "home.jsf" view "http://:8080/website/home.jsf" when I write the following URL "http://:8080/website/caminha/"

How can I achieve this? What I need to change in web.xml or in faces-config.xml? Thanks!

Comment: *What I need to change in web.xml or in faces-config.xml?* Nothing. This can be handled by [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)

Comment: Or, just a plain `Filter` if nothing more's added. Or add home.xhtml to the desired folder (caminha) and do nothing more.